# If $deg f=0$ then $f$ is not surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Among the properties of the degree map in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, there is the property that if $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is not surjective then the degree is $0$.

I'm wondering whether the converse statement is true too - i.e. if $deg f =0$ then $f$ is not surjective.

Intuitively, this seems correct: if we view the degree as the number of times we're wrapping around $S^1$ then if we're not wrapping around even once -- we're not surjective.

Trying to think about how to prove this, I reasoned as follows: I would have to show that $f_* :H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ is the zero map, which means that I'm mapping (equivalence classes of) cycles $\alpha$ in the original space, to a point (?) in the other space (a point, because $\alpha$ must be in Img$\partial_2$, seeing as it's sent to the $0$ class, but since there are no singular $2$-simplices, then this must be sent to the $0$ element in $C_1(S^1)$, which geometrically might represent a point (?), but algebraically it makes no sense because the elements here are formal sums of singular-$1$ simplices). This is clearly not the way to go about it...

I was unable to come up with a counter example either.

Any ideas how to prove/refute?

Comment: in terms of fundamental group: take *any* non-null homotopic closed path and concatenate it with its inverse (/reversed path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are surjective maps with degree $0$. Let $f : S^1 \to J = [-1,1], f(x,y)= x$, and $g : J \to S^1, g(t) = e^{\pi i t}$. These maps are continuous surjections. Thus $g \circ f$ is a continuous surjection which is inessential because $J$ is contractible.

Comment: so the intuition of "no wrap-around" is flawed for degree $0$, right?

Comment: Why is the degree $0$ though? Not sure I'm seeing it through "$J$ is contractible".

Comment: @Anon The Intuition of wrapping around the circle is always okay.  But you have to take inti account that you can "walk" both in positive and negative direction. The map in my answer goes once around the circle in positive direction and the back in negative direction which gives degree $0$. Formally we can argue that the map $g$ us inessential because its domain is contractible. Thus $g \circ f$ is inessential.